# Why is `typename` required in between the template declaration and the return type when the return type is the inner class of a templated class?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, compilation, typename

```
template<typename T>
class Outer
{
    class Inner{};
    
    Inner i;
    T t;
    Inner get();
};

template<typename T> Outer<T>::Inner Outer<T>::get()
{
    return i;
}
```

The above code fails to compile. Adding `typename` in front of `Outer<T>::Inner Outer<T>::get()` solves the problem.

```
template<typename T> typename Outer<T>::Inner Outer<T>::get()
{
    return i;
}
```

I am only used to use `typename` with a `template<>` declaration. I don't understand what `typename` does here and why it is required here. Can you explain the logic of this `typename` here?

Comment: In short, `Outer<T>::Inner` is a *dependent name*, and as such needs the `typename` keyword.

Comment: does this answer your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: You see, I think its this way, only the outer class knows what T is. However, the inner class needs to know that T is a typename. It is simlar to needing to use `typename` when using the template variable inside a templated function: `template <typename T> void foo() { typename std::vector<T> vec; ... }`

Comment: There could be a (partial) specialization of `Outer` where `Inner` is not a type but, say, a member variable of type `int`.